# about the Turtle Library codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, fractals

This is an example of tree create.
To understand the code, I changed some of its numbers to understand what is each code for.

Now in this code, in line 13 although I wrote `lt(90)`, it turns to the left but it turns with 60 angle of degrees, not 90 degrees, why?

Also in line 8 in `pencolor`, why do we use `//`?  Do we only use it in `pencolor`?  What is the number after `level` in `pencolor`?

```
from turtle import *
speed('slowest')
rt(-90)
angle=30
def y(sz, level):
    if level > 0:
        colormode(255)
        pencolor(0, 255//level, 0)
        fd(sz)
        rt(angle)
        y(0.8 * sz, level-1)
        pencolor(0, 255//level, 0)
        lt(90)
        y(0.8 * sz, level-0)
        pencolor(0, 255//level, 0)
        rt(angle)
        fd(-sz)
y(80, 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following code to check lt() and rt() works. For the pencolor() you have to provide a specific color name or you can put a rgb value. It's like pencolor(red, green, blue) or pencolor('color_name'). In pencolor(0, 255//level, 0) you are providing a integer value for the green color by dividing 255//level. If you provide 255/level it will not give you a decimal value. Check the code to understand more

```
import time
from turtle import *
speed('slowest')
rt(-90)
angle=30
def y(sz, level):
    if level > 0:
        colormode(255)
        pencolor(0, 255//level, 0)
        fd(sz)
        rt(angle)
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Moves 80 deg on the right side.")
        y(0.8 * sz, level-1)
        pencolor(0, 255//level, 0)
        lt(90)
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Moves 90 deg on the left side.")
        y(0.8 * sz, level-0)
        time.sleep(5)
        print("These codes are not executes")
        pencolor(0, 255//level, 0)
        rt(angle)
        fd(-sz)
y(80, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, Does 255 // level give the answer to the division or the answer floor division? Because I read that // is for foor division!